# overlapping divs and problem with html on smaller screen devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

So iam working on a website but the problem is that there is a overlap objects over other objects when entering a mobile phone mode
Some elements apears on others and also the screen starts in the buttom not the top
Images :

[image]

as You see there is the sentence: Join with us which does apear above others and also the content starts from buttom and not top

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- FORM SECTION -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- SIGN UP -->
            <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-up">
                <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center sign-up">
                    <div class="form sign-up">
                        <form id="registrationForm">
                            <!-- Your form elements remain unchanged -->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END SIGN UP -->
            <!-- SIGN IN -->
            <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-in">
                <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center sign-in">
                    <div class="form sign-in">
                        <!-- Your sign-in form elements remain unchanged -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    <!-- Additional content if needed -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row content-row">
            <div class="col align-items-center flex-col">
                <div class="text sign-in">
                    <div class="eyes-container">
                        <div class="eye" id="left-eye">
                            <div class="pupil"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="eye" id="right-eye">
                            <div class="pupil"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img sign-in">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col align-items-center flex-col">
                <div class="img sign-up">
                </div>
                <div class="text sign-up">
                    <h2>
                        Join with us
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END SIGN UP CONTENT -->
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT SECTION -->
    </div>
    <script src="/src/js/signup.js"></script>
</body>
```

here is the Body of my html
here is the css

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #ff8fab;
    --secondary-color: #fb6f92;
    --black: #000000;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --gray: #efefef;
    --gray-2: #757575;

    --facebook-color: #4267B2;
    --google-color: #DB4437;
    --twitter-color: #1DA1F2;
    --insta-color: #E1306C;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
}

.align-items-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}

.form-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 28rem;
}

.form {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--white);
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: var(--gray-2);
}

.input-group input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--gray);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--white);
    outline: none;
}

.input-group input:focus {
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--primary-color);
}

.form button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem 0;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    outline: none;
}

.form p {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    font-size: .7rem;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.social-list {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}

.social-list>div {
    color: var(--white);
    margin: 0 .5rem;
    padding: .7rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.social-list>div:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 1.4s;
}

.social-list>div:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 1.6s;
}

.social-list>div:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 1.8s;
}

.social-list>div:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

.social-list>div>i {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.social-list>div:hover i {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.facebook-bg {
    background-color: var(--facebook-color);
}

.google-bg {
    background-color: var(--google-color);
}

.twitter-bg {
    background-color: var(--twitter-color);
}

.insta-bg {
    background-color: var(--insta-color);
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container.sign-in .form.sign-in,
.container.sign-in .social-list.sign-in,
.container.sign-in .social-list.sign-in>div,
.container.sign-up .form.sign-up,
.container.sign-up .social-list.sign-up,
.container.sign-up .social-list.sign-up>div {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.content-row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    margin: 4rem;
    color: var(--white);
}

.text h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.text p {
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.img img {
    width: 30vw;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.text.sign-in h2,
.text.sign-in p,
.img.sign-in img {
    transform: translateX(-250%);
}

.text.sign-up h2,
.text.sign-up p,
.img.sign-up img {
    transform: translateX(250%);
}

.container.sign-in .text.sign-in h2,
.container.sign-in .text.sign-in p,
.container.sign-in .img.sign-in img,
.container.sign-up .text.sign-up h2,
.container.sign-up .text.sign-up p,
.container.sign-up .img.sign-up img {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

/* BACKGROUND */

.container::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300vw;
    transform: translate(35%, 0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--primary-color) 0%, var(--secondary-color) 100%);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 6;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: max(50vw, 50vh);
    border-top-left-radius: max(50vw, 50vh);
}

.container.sign-in::before {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    right: 50%;
}

.container.sign-up::before {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
    right: 50%;
}

/* RESPONSIVE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {

    .container::before,
    .container.sign-in::before,
    .container.sign-up::before {
        height: 100vh;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        transform: none;
        right: 0;
    }

    /* .container.sign-in .col.sign-up {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    } */

    .container.sign-in .col.sign-in,
    .container.sign-up .col.sign-up {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    .content-row {
        align-items: flex-start !important;
    }

    .content-row .col {
        transform: translateY(0);
        background-color: unset;
    }

    .col {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: var(--white);
        border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .row {
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .form,
    .social-list {
        box-shadow: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .text {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .text p {
        display: none;
    }

    .text h2 {
        margin: .5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

.gender-selection {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.gender-option {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gender-button {
    background: var(--white);
    color:var(--gray-2) ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.gender-button:hover {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.gender-option input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.gender-option input[type="radio"]:checked + .gender-button {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

/*
    Gender Intersted iN Selecter
*/

.gender-selection-in {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.gender-option-in {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gender-button-in {
    background: var(--white);
    color:var(--gray-2) ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.gender-button-in:hover {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.gender-option-in input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.gender-option-in input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .gender-button-in {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.gender-option-in .gender-button-in:not(:checked) {
    background: var(--white);
    color:var(--gray-2) ;
}
.divider {
    height: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.genederlabel{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: var(--gray-2);
    
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#gender-label.error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.gender-selection-in.error {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}


.eyes-container {
    display: flex;
}

.eye {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Added box shadow */
}

.pupil {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

so anyone can help?

I tried some solutions from the Internet which did not work

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I think is you have added overflow:hidden; in html, body and container, which will stop scroll of screen. That's why elements are being visible like that and not from bottom but in single screen. So to make it right remove overflow or set your elements as per size of screen height to make it all visible properly. Still if not solved it would be more good if you provide full html.